# How to subset list of items from apriori rules?

Tags: r, apriori, arules

So I've accomplished arules model and got list of rules with different items. To find if rules contain a specific item in lhs or rhs the code is the following:
`rules.sub <- subset(rules, subset = items %in% "item_to_match")`. 
However, my goal concerns not finding one specific item, but to match a list of items from separate csv and find all rules, which contain them. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

UPD: As I've understood, it may be accomplished through subset method. However, the final code should be a bit different. The subset method throws an error, if you specify some item, which is not in list, but it can be bypassed by the following code:

1) Create find results function:

`fn_findRules <- function(rules, newBasket){ arules<-subset(rules, items %in% newBasket) return (arules) }` (Thx to @lukeA , [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063302/arules-package-error-in-lhs-ain-newbasket-table-contains-an-unknown-item-lab))

 2) Creating variable with results, which uses defined function

`resuslts <- fn_findRules(rules, intersect(itemLabels(rules), table_with_items_to_check))`